# Flutter - SpriteWidget gets zero height, Image Widget does not in the same row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flame

I have an app that is using a SpriteSheet from Flame to select the proper image (a playing card).  The screen will show a five card hand, initially with all card backs (null value in the hand), and as cards are selected and added to the hand, they should display with the face.  The problem I am running into is that the SpriteWidget ends up with a zero height, but the Image widget that holds the placeholder card back does not.  The overall route has a Container->BlocBuilder->Column, and this widget is one of the children on that column widget.

Here's the code as is:
Get the card face from the spritesheet (in CommonAssets class):

```
static SpriteWidget getCardFace(Card card) =>
    SpriteWidget(sprite: cardSprites!.getSprite(card.value-2, card.suit.index));
```

Build the hand to be shown on the screen:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget cardWidget(int index, PlayHandState state) {
      final Card? card = state.hand.cardAt(index);
      final Widget graphic = card != null
        ? CommonAssets.getCardFace(card)
        : Image.asset(CommonAssets.cardPlaceholder);
      return Expanded(
        child: graphic
      );
    }

    return BlocBuilder<PlayHandBloc, PlayHandState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            color: const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: List.generate(state.hand.maxCards, (index) => cardWidget(index, state)),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

If I run this with a bloc state holding a hand with a single card, I get a blank spot, then four placeholder images.  Width is correct, and the placeholder aspect ratio is correct.  Looking at the widget tree in the Inspector, the Row's RenderFlex has constraints of 0.0<=w<=361.4, and an unconstrained height - h=98.1.  The SpriteWidget has sizes of w=72.3, and h=0.0. The Image widget right next to it has a w=72.3 and h=98.1.  I'm not sure why the Image gets a height but the SpriteWidget does not.

**Things I've tried:**

1. I know the spritesheet works in general, because I use it elsewhere, specifically in a GridView.  I tried replacing the Row widget with essentially the same GridView that is used elsewhere, and card faces do show up.  To do that, I removed the Expanded and replaced the Row with:

```
GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount: state.hand.maxCards,
   crossAxisSpacing: 5,
   mainAxisSpacing: 5,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   childAspectRatio: .75,
   children: List.generate(state.hand.maxCards, (index) => cardWidget(index, state)),
),
```

There were other really odd problems with this that would end up being a different question, and GridView just didn't seem like the right control anyway, it was just a test to make sure the cardWidget function was working here.
ListView also didn't seem right - this is not a scrollable control, just a simple five images in a row, with zero or more coming from a spritesheet for efficiency.

2. I tried wrapping the BlocBuilder in an Expanded to see if that would add a height constraint, but it didn't and then the widget was too tall, so that failed all the way around :) .
3. The last thing I tried was to wrap the BlocBuilder in a Container with a constraint setting the maxHeight, which also had no effect other than to cause a renderflex to overflow in the parent Column.

Comment: I'm currently thinking this may be a bug in SpriteSheet.  When I mentioned "other really odd problems" above, that was SpriteSheet producing an incorrect image - caching and re-using an already shown image instead of the requested sprite.  Because of that, I just pulled SpriteSheet and replaced it with a Map, and now everything works perfectly - Row or Grid (using Row as the more appropriate control).  Putting this as a comment, because it isn't a solution, just my work-around.

Comment: Thanks for a very well written question! I'll have a look to see if I can spot any bugs regarding this in `SpriteSheet`. It does sound like such a normal use case though that I'm surprised that it hasn't been reported before if there actually is a bug with the height.

Comment: @spydon I pulled this down to an almost minimal test app, it;s in https://github.com/bryantgtx/zero-ht-sprite if that helps.

Comment: that's very helpful! Could you open an issue on GitHub which contains that link so that other maintainers can see it too?

Comment: Oh, but SO is so much easier :).  Done - https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/1575, and https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/1577

Comment: Thanks! Agree, but hard to track it on SO though. 